# Increase speed of numpy operations on large number of vectors

Tags: python, arrays, vectorization, numpy-ndarray, numpy-einsum

I would like a faster implementation of the functions shown below.  Ideally the code should work when `number_points` variable is set to 400-500.  Is there any way I can improve the function definitions to increase speed (see sample run)?

[image: Here is a sample run showing a slow execution]

Here is my code:

```py
import numpy as np
import time

def initialize_plane_points(Domain = 100,number_points=200,Plane_Offset=0.0):
    '''Domain has implied coordinates of mm and the number of 
    points represents the number of samples within that space.  '''
    X = np.linspace(-Domain,Domain,number_points)
    #print(X)
    Y = np.linspace(-Domain,Domain,number_points)
    #print(Y)
    ZZ = np.array([])
    XX,YY = np.meshgrid(X,Y)
    for x in XX:
        for y in YY:
            ZZ = np.append(ZZ,[Plane_Offset])
    ZZ = np.reshape(ZZ, (len(XX),len(YY)))
    
    Shape = np.array([])
    for i in range(len(XX)):
        for j in range(len(YY)):
            Shape = np.append(Shape,[XX[i,j],YY[i,j],ZZ[i,j]])
    a = int(len(Shape) / 3)
    SHAPE = np.reshape(Shape,(a,3))
    return SHAPE



T0 = time.perf_counter()
Points = initialize_plane_points(number_points=100)
T1 = time.perf_counter()
    
    print("100 initialize time: ",T1-T0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a general rule, if you want efficient code with `numpy` you want as few loop iterations as possible.

`np.append` as also relatively slow. Instead, try to build your arrays with vectorial algebra. For instance, `ZZ = np.ones((len(XX),len(YY)) * Plane_Offset` will be a lot faster than the two nested loops you have.

Answer (score 0):

[New Results for array generation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJbL8.png)
The function was rewritten avoiding any explicit for loops.  The difference in time is amazing.  I would love to know how these functions are so efficient.

```
def initialize_plane_points_2(Domain = 100,number_points=200,Plane_Offset=0.0):
    X = np.linspace(-Domain,Domain,number_points)
    Y = np.linspace(-Domain,Domain,number_points)
    
    XX,YY = np.meshgrid(X,Y)
    ZZ = np.ones((len(XX),len(YY)))*Plane_Offset
    #print(ZZ.shape, XX.shape,YY.shape)
    
    Shape = np.dstack((XX,YY,ZZ)).reshape(-1,3)
    return Shape
```

Comment: These functions are efficient because they are implemented in [a backend written in C](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/internals.html), and Python just executes that. The backend uses [SIMD operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44944367/are-numpys-basic-operations-vectorized-i-e-do-they-use-simd-operations) to perform the same operation on multiple data instead of iteratively loading each data to operate on.