# An efficient way to iterate over a multidimensional array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, loops

I'm trying to find a way to perform operations on each elements across multiple 2D-arrays without having to loop over them. Or at least, not needing two `for` loops. My code calculates the standard deviation of each pixel over a series of images (arrays). Now, the amount of images there are is not the problem, it is the size of the arrays, making the code take extremely slow. The following is a working example of what I have.

```
import numpy as np

# reshape(# of image (arrays),# of rows, # of cols) 
a = np.arange(32).reshape(2,4,4)

stddev_arr = np.array([])
for i in range(4):
    for j in range(4): 
        pixel = a[0:,i,j]
        stddev = np.std(pixel) 
        stddev_arr = np.append(stddev_arr, stddev)
```

My actual data is 2000x2000, making this code loop 4000000 times. Is there a better way to do this?
Any advice is extremely appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're already using `numpy`. numpy's [`std()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.std.html) function takes an `axis` argument that tells it what axis you want it to operate on (in this case the zeroth axis). Because this offloads the calculation to numpy's C-backend (and possibly using [SIMD optimizations](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/simd/simd-optimizations.html) for your processor that [vectorize a lot of operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44944367/are-numpys-basic-operations-vectorized-i-e-do-they-use-simd-operations)), it's *so much* faster than iterating. Another time-consuming operation in your code is when you append to `stddev_arr`. Appending to numpy arrays is *slow* because the *entire array* is copied into new memory before the new element is added. Now you already know how big that array needs to be, so you might as well preallocate it.

```
a = np.arange(32).reshape(2, 4, 4)
stdev = np.std(a, axis=0)
```

This gives a `4x4` array

```
array([[8., 8., 8., 8.],
       [8., 8., 8., 8.],
       [8., 8., 8., 8.],
       [8., 8., 8., 8.]])
```

To flatten this into a 1D array, do `flat_stdev = stdev.flatten()`.

Comparing the execution times:

```
# Using only numpy
def fun1(arr):
    return np.std(arr, axis=0).flatten()

# Your function
def fun2(arr):
    stddev_arr = np.array([])
    for i in range(arr.shape[1]):
        for j in range(arr.shape[2]): 
            pixel = arr[0:,i,j]
            stddev = np.std(pixel) 
            stddev_arr = np.append(stddev_arr, stddev)
    return stddev_arr


# Your function, but pre-allocating stddev_arr
def fun3(arr):
    stddev_arr = np.zeros((arr.shape[1] * arr.shape[2],))
    x = 0
    for i in range(arr.shape[1]):
        for j in range(arr.shape[2]): 
            pixel = arr[0:,i,j]
            stddev = np.std(pixel) 
            stddev_arr[x] = stddev
            x += 1
    return stddev_arr
```

First, let's make sure all these functions are equivalent:

```
a = np.random.random((3, 10, 10))
assert np.all(fun1(a) == fun2(a))
assert np.all(fun1(a) == fun3(a))
```

Yup, all give the same result. Now, let's try with a bigger array.

```
a = np.random.random((3, 100, 100))

x = timeit.timeit('fun1(a)', setup='from __main__ import fun1, a', number=10)
# x: 0.003302899989648722

y = timeit.timeit('fun2(a)', setup='from __main__ import fun2, a', number=10)
# y: 5.495519500007504

z = timeit.timeit('fun3(a)', setup='from __main__ import fun3, a', number=10)
# z: 3.6250679999939166
```

Wow! We get a ~1.5x speedup just by preallocating.
Even more wow: using numpy's `std()` with the `axis` argument gives a > 1000x speedup, and this is just for the `100x100` array! With bigger arrays, you can expect to see *even bigger* speedup.

Comment: This has been really helpful, thank you very much! By using pre-allocating I have a ~12x speedup!

Answer (score 1):

So based on what you have provided, you can reshape your array in another way to vectorize it to replace your two loops. Then you only have to use `np.std` once on the axis that you want.

```
a = np.arange(32).reshape(2, 4, 4)

a = a.reshape(2, -1).transpose()

stddev_arr = np.std(a, axis=1)
```

Comment: Why does it need to be reshaped or transposed? `np.std(np.arange(32).reshape(2,4,4), axis=0)` works just fine.

Comment: Yes, but your solution gives a 2d array, which have to be reshaped anyway. It's down to preference and I prefer to do it before the operation. Your solution works as well.

Comment: Can you start this solution from `a = np.arange(32).reshape(2,4,4)` which was OP's sample dataset. Presumably that matches the real array being worked with.