# No speedup when summing uint16 vs uint64 arrays with NumPy?

Tags: python, numpy, performance, compiler-optimization, simd

I have to do a large number of operations (additions) on relatively small integers, and I started considering which datatype would give the best performance on a 64 bit machine.

I was convinced that adding together 4 `uint16` would take the same time as one `uint64`, since the ALU could make 4 `uint16` additions using only 1 `uint64` adder.  (Carry propagation means this doesn't work that easily for a single 64-bit adder, but this is how integer SIMD instructions work.)

Apparently this is not the case:

```
In [3]: data = np.random.rand(10000)

In [4]: int16 = data.astype(np.uint16)

In [5]: int64 = data.astype(np.uint64)

In [6]: int32 = data.astype(np.uint32)

In [7]: float32 = data.astype(np.float32)

In [8]: float64 = data.astype(np.float64)

In [9]: %timeit int16.sum()
13.4 µs ± 43.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

In [10]: %timeit int32.sum()
13.9 µs ± 347 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

In [11]: %timeit int64.sum()
9.33 µs ± 47.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

In [12]: %timeit float32.sum()
5.79 µs ± 6.51 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

In [13]: %timeit float64.sum()
6 µs ± 3.54 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

All int operations take the same time (more than the float ops) with no speedup. Is this due the C implementation of numpy not being fully optimized or is there some hardware limitation that I am not aware of?

Comment: *with no optimization* makes all your performance tests void. It makes no sense to do ant performance tests without optimizations

Comment: Sorry, i meant 'no speedup'. I am not the one compiling numpy, and I am pretty sure that the numpy developers compile their code with optimization turned on.

Comment: "the ALU could make 4 uint16 additions using only 1 uint64 adder" - in principle this would be possible, but in order to do that, it would need to not propagate the carry between the 4 16-bit parts.

Comment: x86-64 has SIMD integer add with 8, 16, 32, or 64-bit element width, and those instructions all have the same performance (https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/paddb:paddw:paddd:paddq).  (@mkrieger1: that's what SIMD is for.  We don't normally call it "the ALU", though, partly because CPUs with SIMD normally also have multiple execution units).  A well-optimized asm loop (generated by a C compiler) should run at the same speed in bytes per cycle (e.g. 2x 32-byte vectors loaded and summed per clock cycle, if data is hot in L1d cache), whether that's 2x 16x uint16 or 2x 4x uint64.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Ah! that's why... I did not think of the carry bit at all. Makes sense now. Thanks!

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44944367/are-numpys-basic-operations-vectorized-i-e-do-they-use-simd-operations - so the question is why didn't it have an effect in your example.

Comment: This probably doesn't matter, but are you aware all your integer arrays are full of zeros?

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica oops, forgot that random gives out 0-1. Tried with real random data and I get the same results.

Comment: @mkrieger1: Actually it maybe does: if NumPy integer routines are only using SSE2, not dispatching based on availability of AVX2, that would explain why they'd run at half speed for data hot in cache if the CPU is a modern x86-64.  Aren't these arrays all the same size in bytes, not in elements?  I don't really know Python or NumPy, but I'm guessing `data.astype(np.uint16)` is just a reinterpret of the same data bytes with a different type.  So 4x as many uint16 elements as uint64.

Comment: @PeterCordes Wait.. does that mean that there would be a way to get the speed up then? But that numpy is compiled in a way that does not take advantage of it?

Comment: @PeterCordes The number of elements in each array is the same.

Comment: NumPy does have some SIMD code (see for example https://github.com/numpy/numpy/tree/main/numpy/core/src/common/simd and https://github.com/numpy/numpy/tree/main/numpy/core/src/_simd), but I know very little about it. However, I believe operations on two separate, C-contiguous arrays (such as `int16 + int16`) get more development focus than reduction operations (like `int16.sum()`). `int16 + int16` may trigger a SIMD code path if `int16.sum()` doesn't.

Comment: Note that it may be difficult to distinguish SIMD effects from the effect of simply reading less memory in the cases with smaller dtypes.

Comment: @PeterCordes `np.astype` returns a copy of the array, not just a reinterpret of the same data bytes. [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html)

Comment: @pnjun: Thanks, that makes sense for the function name.  I was thinking in low-level SIMD terms given the question and that possible explanation, but NumPy is a high-level library, not low-level like C `__m128i` intrinsics.   Or especially the C# System.Numerics intrinsics library where I think you do `.AsByte()` on a `Vector<128>` to get a type that has 16 byte elements, vs. `.AsInt64()` to get the same SIMD vector as 2x int64, to imply an operand-size for an intrinsic like `Sse2.Add()` (i.e. `paddq` vs. `paddb`).  Makes sense for a short-vector SIMD type, less sense for high-level arrays :P

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica i just tried it with arrays that are the actual same size in memory (4 times as many elements in `int16` as in `int64`) and still no speedup. So that does not seem to be the case.

Comment: I just tried two 80000-byte arrays, one with uint16 dtype and one with uint64 dtype, and got roughly the same timing for `x + x` whether `x` was the 16-bit array or the 64-bit array.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Yep, tired it as well and have the same. So it seems that for the + operator it is using SIMD, but not for sum().

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**TL;DR:** I made an experimental analysis on Numpy 1.21.1. Experimental results show that **`np.sum` does NOT (really) make use of SIMD instructions**: no SIMD instruction are used for integers, and scalar SIMD instructions are used for floating-point numbers! Moreover, Numpy **converts the integers to 64-bits values** for smaller integer types by default so to avoid *overflows*!

---

Note that this may not reflect all Numpy versions since there is an ongoing work to provide SIMD support for commonly used functions (the version [Numpy 1.22.0rc1](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/releases) not yet released continue this long-standing work). Moreover, the compiler or the processor used may significantly impact the results. The following experiments have been done using a Numpy retrieved from pip on a Debian Linux with a i5-9600KF processor.

---

### Under the hood of `np.sum`

For floating-point numbers, Numpy uses a *pairwise algorithm* which is known to be quite *numerically stable* while being relatively fast. This can be seen in the code, but also simply using a profiler: `TYPE_pairwise_sum` is the C function called to compute the sum at runtime (where `TYPE` is `DOUBLE` or `FLOAT`).

For integers, Numpy use a classical naive reduction. The C function called is `ULONG_add_avx2` on AVX2-compatible machines. It also surprisingly convert items to 64-bit ones if the type is not `np.int64`.

Here is the hot part of the assembly code executed by the `DOUBLE_pairwise_sum` function

```
  3,65 │ a0:┌─→add        $0x8,%rcx                  ; Loop iterator
  3,60 │    │  prefetcht0 (%r8,%rax,1)               ; Prefetch data
  9,46 │    │  vaddsd     (%rax,%rbp,1),%xmm1,%xmm1  ; Accumulate an item in xmm1[0]
  4,65 │    │  vaddsd     (%rax),%xmm0,%xmm0         ; Same for xmm0[0]
  6,91 │    │  vaddsd     (%rax,%rdx,1),%xmm4,%xmm4  ; Etc.
  7,77 │    │  vaddsd     (%rax,%rdx,2),%xmm7,%xmm7
  7,41 │    │  vaddsd     (%rax,%r10,1),%xmm2,%xmm2
  7,27 │    │  vaddsd     (%rax,%rdx,4),%xmm6,%xmm6
  6,80 │    │  vaddsd     (%rax,%r11,1),%xmm3,%xmm3
  7,46 │    │  vaddsd     (%rax,%rbx,1),%xmm5,%xmm5
  3,46 │    │  add        %r12,%rax                  ; Switch to the next items (x8)
  0,13 │    ├──cmp        %rcx,%r9                   ; Should the loop continue?
  3,27 │    └──jg         a0                         ; Jump to the beginning if so
```

The Numpy compiled code clearly uses the **scalar SIMD instruction** `vaddsd` (computing only a single double-precision item) although it successfully *unroll the loop* 8 times. The same code is generated for `FLOAT_pairwise_sum`: `vaddss` is called 8 times.

For the `np.uint32`, here is the hot part of the generated assembly code:

```
  2,37 │160:┌─→add          $0x1,%rax     ; Loop iterator
 95,95 │    │  add          (%rdi),%rdx   ; Accumulate the values in %rdx
  0,06 │    │  add          %r10,%rdi     ; Switch to the next item
       │    ├──cmp          %rsi,%rax     ; Should the loop continue?
  1,08 │    └──jne          160           ; Jump to the beginning if so
```

Numpy obviously does not use SIMD instructions for `np.uint32` type. It does not even unroll the loop. The `add (%rdi),%rdx` instruction performing the accumulation is the bottleneck here due to the data dependency on the accumulator. The same loops can be seen for np.uint64`(despite the name of the function is`ULONG_add_avx2`).

However, the `np.uint32` version call the C function `_aligned_contig_cast_uint_to_ulong` in order to **convert the integer items to a wider type**. Numpy does that to **avoid integer overflows**. The same thing can be seen for the types `np.uint8` and `np.uint16` (although the name of the function differs). Hopefully, this function makes use of SIMD instructions (SSE) but still takes a significant portion of the execution time (~30% of the `np.sum` time).

**EDIT**: as pointed out by @user2357112supportsMonica, the `dtype` parameter of `np.sum` can be explicitly specified. When it match with the `dtype` of the input array, then the conversion is not performed. This results in a smaller execution time at the expense of a possible overflow.

---

### Benchmark results

Here is the result on my machine:

```
uint16: 7.17 µs ± 80 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 20000 loops each)
uint32: 7.11 µs ± 12.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 20000 loops each)
uint64: 5.05 µs ± 8.57 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 20000 loops each)
float32: 2.88 µs ± 9.27 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 20000 loops each)
float64: 3.06 µs ± 10.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 20000 loops each)
```

First of all, not that the results are very similar to the ones provided in the question meaning that the behavior seen on my machine can be successfully reproduced on other one. Thus, the explanation should also be consistent.

As you can see, the 64-bit version is faster than the other integer-based versions. This is due to the overhead of the conversion. The two first are equally+fast because of the scalar loop and the `add` instruction being equally-fast for 8-bit, 16-bit and 32-bit integers (this should be true for most 64-bit mainstream platforms). The integer implementations are slower than the floating-point ones because of the lack of (proper) loop unrolling.

The floating-point implementations are equally-fast due to the scalar SIMD instructions. Indeed, the instructions `vaddss` (for `np.float32`) and `vaddsd` (for `np.float64`) have the same latency and throughput (at least on all modern Intel processors). Thus the throughput of the two implementation is the same since the loop of the two implementation is similar (same unrolling).

---

### Additional notes

This is sad `np.sum` does not fully make use of SIMD instructions as this would speed up a lot the computations using it (especially small integers).

**[UPDATE]** Looking at the Numpy code, I discovered that the code is not vectorized because the **array stride is a runtime value** and the compiler do not generate a specialized version where the stride is 1. In fact, this can be partially seen in the previous assembly code: the compiler used the instruction `add %r10, %rdi` because `%r10` (the stride of the target array) is not known at compile-time. There is currently no optimization for this specific case of reduction in the Numpy code yet (the functions are relatively generic). This may change in a near future.

In addition to the stride problem, one big point makes it hard for compilers to automatically vectorize a code: the floating-point addition is [not commutative, nor associative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24442725/is-floating-point-addition-commutative-in-c) (unless flags like `-ffast-math` are used).

Comment: Oh, right. I totally forgot about the weird default dtype behavior `numpy.sum` and `numpy.ndarray.sum` have. What do you see if you explicitly do something like `int16.sum(dtype='uint16')`?

Comment: (I see a significant speedup relative to the default behavior, but I'm curious what gets executed.)

Comment: Good point! This avoid the overhead of the expensive conversion since the function  `_aligned_contig_cast_ushort_to_ulong` is not called anymore (at the expense of a possible 16-bit overflow). As a result, `int16.sum(dtype='uint16')` is about 30% faster on my machine (consistent with the benchmark).

Comment: SIMD summation without integer overflow isn't hard, you just unpack with zeros.  All mainstream SIMD ISAs have shuffles that make it possible to do that.  For integer stuff it's easy to get identical results even with different vectorization strategies (because there's never any rounding, or if you do it right no overflow of any accumulators narrower than the final result), so you can manually vectorize for some common ISAs but not others without any observable change in behaviour except performance, so the non-portability SIMD isn't much of an excuse.  (It's baseline for x86-64 and ARM64.)

Comment: (There are some per-architecture tricks like x86 using `pmaddwd` with `_mm_set1_epi16(1)`to horizontal sum pairs of int16 into int32 more efficiently than unpacking low/high with zeros for unsigned or SSE4.1 `pmovsxwd` for signed, and only widening to 64-bit elements in an outer loop after some number of iterations that guarantees 32-bit sums of 16-bit elements won't overflow.  Or to sum bytes without overflow, x86 `psadbw` against `_mm_setzero_si128()`.  See [Fastest way to do horizontal SSE vector sum](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35270026) but just widen elements, not all the way to scalar)

Comment: @JérômeRichard Thanks a lot for the detailed answer! This thread has been a great discussion all-around and I've learned a lot! I'll try to see if I can modify my code to use `sum(dtype=...)` explicitly

Comment: @PeterCordes Indeed, it is not hard for developers familiar with SIMD intrinsics, but compilers tends to fail to generate efficient SIMD codes for non trivial reductions due to that (here it should be ok, but the compiler used to build Numpy obviously failed). I agree for the portability in this case, but not in general: Numpy target a lot of platforms and supports different types (eg. complex numbers) and supporting all of them efficiently and in a maintainable way (in C) for a lot of operations is tricky (mainly due to the dispatch and the fragmentation of the ISA, especially x86-64).

Comment: SSE2 is baseline for x86-64, so is SIMD for AArch64.  So those two mainstream / "important" ISAs could at least use C that can auto-vectorize, if not intrinsics.  For example, GCC and clang have no problem doing a decent job auto-vectorizing with SSE2 for summing uint16_t to uint64_t.  https://godbolt.org/z/o7zba9zfv just compiled with `-O3`, no other optimization options.  Using `-march=haswell` or `skylake-avx512` would allow better code (especially for clang which makes poor choices, using narrow loads and needing more shuffles per vector of results).  Still probably faster than scalar.

Comment: So yeah it's non-trivial, but not that hard.  Maybe they were just using GCC `-O2`, not `-O3`.  Mostly my comments were aimed at your point about using SIMD being hard because it's different on different ISAs.  Yeah it's more fragmentation of the source to maintain more manually-vectorized versions, but if the numerical results are identical (integer) you at least don't have that concern about matching it with scalar code.

Comment: @PeterCordes Indeed, in this case, the auto-vectorization is good. I just discovered that the problem of the vectorization do not comes from the compiler nor compiler flags, but from the Numpy code itself ;) ! I edited the answer. Thanks you.

Comment: Ah, that fully explains it, good find.  (But note that IEEE754 FP addition *is* commutative, and a compiler knows that when it's compiling for x86-64 with IEEE754 math semantics.  The "no" answers on the linked question are talking ISO C++'s lack of a guarantee because of portability to hypothetical weird non-IEEE754 systems.  Of course associativity is the important one, commutativity is minor: [Associativity gives us parallelizability. But what does commutativity give?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35443424))